# Разработка железа для Linux

Tags: linux, stm32

Уже есть некоторый опыт разработки устройств на микроконтроллерах (stm32), хочу попробовать разработать что-то, на чём можно будет запустить линукс. Можете подсказать какие-нибудь книги или статьи по теме? Как разработать аппаратную часть? И как подготовить дистрибутив для работы на ней?

Comment: В сторону raspberry, banana, odroid уже смотрели?

Comment: Смотрел, но хочется чего-то более простого для начала, и хочется не просто повторять, а понять и научиться делать такие вещи самому) Так то и на целые ноутбуки есть схемы в открытом доступе - бери да повторяй)

Comment: Сейчас обычно производители кристаллов дают бинарник линуксовый, который уже собран под этот кристалл. Ну и исходники тоже дают. Поищите такого производителя из первой пятерки, купите прототипную плату  (долларов 100 это обойдется) и пользуйтесь.

Comment: Спасибо, не знал об этом)

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста. Но учтите, что там могут быть чудовищные косяки, как-то: не соответствуют исходники собранному бинарнику, не транслируются исходники с предложенным транслятором, падает линукс после 1-2-5-24 часов работы. Так что сначала почитайте отзывы, а потом покупайте. И вообще, такие вопросы лучше задавать на форумах электронщиков. Раньше это были телесистемы, а теперь они куда-то переехали. Поищите и найдете и там спросите. Народ такими делами занимается, хоть и мало. Что-нибудь да посоветуют насчет качества сборки Линукса и полноты документации у разных фирм.

Comment: Любой arm где памяти хватит)

Comment: В любом нет MMU) А он нужен для всех линуксов кроме uClinux. Кроме того, допустим, я взял чип который удовлетворяет всем требованиям по аппаратной части: у него достаточно высокая тактовая частота, есть MMU, я прикрутил к нему достаточно RAM и FLASH. Как запустить на нём линукс? Если я просто возьму дистрибутив и подключу карту памяти с ним к процессору - ничего не произойдёт

Comment: @User_0, зависит от устройства конкретного чипа, так что что-то общее сказать сложно... В типовом варианте (когда у чипа есть собственная небольшая флешка на борту и он просто запускает то что в ней записано с определённого адреса памяти) обычно в чип заливают загрузчик, в котором прописано, где искать ядро и корневую ФС. И загрузчик просто копирует ядро в RAM хоть из внутренней памяти, хоть со внешней флешки, хоть по сети и передаёт ему управление... так что после сборки загрузчика всё будет выглядеть как «я просто возьму дистрибутив и подключу карту памяти с ним к процессору»…

Comment: Отлично, теперь гораздо понятнее. Итак, я беру подходящий чип, прикручиваю к нему достаточное количество RAM и карту памяти. Пишу для чипа прошивку, которая при старте просто находит на флешке загрузчик ОС, копирует его в RAM, и передаёт ему управление. Теперь вопрос: загрузчик ОС же должен знать, например, адресацию памяти в чипе, адреса регистров? Как ему передать всю эту информацию? Или это происходит автоматически при компиляции? Или в ОС все эти функции реализованы абстрактно и нужно просто написать низкоуровневые функции, которые будут прослойкой между ОС и аппаратной частью?

Comment: @User_0, поправлю, на маленьких—средних системах обычно **загрузчик** и есть та прошивка, которая находится в чипе, а на флешке находит уже **ядро ОС**, но на больших системах может быть и как ты описал... AFAIK, базовые адреса памяти в загрузчике задаются обычно на стадии конфигурации/компиляции. Ядро может получать эту информацию от загрузчика через свою командную строку, через devicetree (от загрузчика, вшитое в ядро или из файла) или может быть сконфигурировано со всем вшитыми данными... ЗЫ: используй упоминание через собаку в комментариях — иначе можно не получить ответа...

Comment: Нам уже готовое собранное ядро присылают на этих платах https://www.mev.co.uk/pages/Software-Design/Linux.html можете глянуть в их документации, вполне обширна. Камень ARM

Comment: @Hellseher, спасибо)